# Camera 3D rotation with DirectX11

Tags: c++, camera, rotation, directx

I try to create a camera for an fbx viewer with DirectX11 in C++. I succeds to do translation but not rotation. In my class Camera, I have 2 landmark : my camera and my target (they have both an up vector, right vector, lookAt vector and a position).

To do rotation, I proceed like that :

```
void
    Camera::upRotation(float angle)
{
    using namespace DirectX;
    XMMATRIX    yaw;

    yaw = XMMatrixRotationAxis(XMLoadFloat3(&this->targetUp), XMConvertToRadians(angle));
    XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&this->cameraLookAt), yaw);
    XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&this->targetLookAt), yaw);
    XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&this->cameraRight), yaw);
    XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&this->targetRight), yaw);
}
```

To update my viewMatrix I :

1. Normalize vector View, Up, Right and check if they're mutually
   orthogonal (for target and camera)
2. Update my camera position
3. Fill my viewMatrix with new element :

[ cameraRight.x ; cameraUp.x ; cameraLookAt.x ; 0.0f

cameraRight.y ; cameraUp.y ; cameraLookAt.y ; 0.0f

cameraRight.z ; cameraUp.z ; cameraLookAt.z ; 0.0f

cameraRight . cameraPos ; cameraUp . cameraPos ; cameraLookAt .cameraPos ; 1.0f ]

But when I test, the rotation don't do anything (but it goes into the function). What am I doing wrong ? And is my logic correct or I should do my camera otherwise ?

Answer (score 1):

You already have some pre-made functions for you if you prefer them:

[XMMatrixLookAtLH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixlookatlh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

or

[XMMatrixLookToLH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixlooktolh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

They should do exactly what you need (and you have the source code for them).